# React compare or match date from restapi data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, compare

I am facing an issue in React JS. How shoud i compare or match the `header` date from rest api `start_date`. It show in render in Component Page.

Rest API

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"staff_name": "Jill",
"custom_service_name": "Jone",
"start_date": "2020-05-06 11:30:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-06 11:45:00",
},
{
"id": "2",
"staff_name": "james",
"custom_service_name": "smith",
"start_date": "2020-05-06 11:00:00",
"end_date": "2020-05-06 11:15:00",
}
]
```

Component Page:

```
var headerdate = ['11:00 AM', '11:30 AM', '12:00 AM'];


  this.state = {
      appointmentdata:[],      
    }
  } 

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/route/v1/appointment`)
      .then(res => {
        const appointmentdata = res.data;
        console.log(appointmentdata);
        this.setState({ appointmentdata });
      })
  }


render() {  
  return (
    <div>
         // write your compare or match dates code here 
      {this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => <p>{data.start_date}</p>) }
   </div>
  )
}
```

I try but i can't make the logic

```
if (data.start_date === this.state.headerdate ....
```

**Expected Output**

[image]

just match or compare `start_date` with `header` date

What should i do? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you help me there as well? [@Ajeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873538/ajeet-shah)

Comment: i need your help? Can you solve this issue?[@rehan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13445986/rehan-s)

Comment: i have an similar issue date compare [@Ashish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4976422/ashish-ranjan)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Momentjs([MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/))

install it first `npm install moment --save`

import it `import moment from "moment";` in your component

```
const dateTime = moment(data.start_date.toString());
if(dateTime.format('h:mm A')===this.state.headerdate){
// your code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but what should i write in code? [@Menji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239185/besufkad-menji)

Comment: can you write the code? please [@Menji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239185/besufkad-menji)

Comment: Failed to compile 'data' is not defined  [@Menji](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10239185/besufkad-menji)

Comment: `render() {  

return (
    <div>
      // write your compare or match dates code here
      {this.state.appointmentdata.map(data => {
        const dateTime = moment(data.start_date.toString());
        if (dateTime.format("h:mm A") === this.state.headerdate) {
          return <p>{dateTime.format("h:mm A")}</p>;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );

}

  )`